# In ZFC given any set $X$ if $x\in X$ then is $\emptyset=x\cap X$?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

Given any set $X$ and any element $x\in X$ then is $\emptyset=x\cap X$?

Feels like it should be, I mean most of the time I don't even think of elements of sets as sets unless I'm deliberate doing so. Though I know if like I'm working in ZFC or something, then like pretty much everything I write is a set I think. Anyway an answer to the first question would be helpful.

Also if yes, what axiom(s) would it follow from? All of them? Only a couple?

Lastly if in modern axiomatic set theory essentially everything is a set wouldn't things like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_function

Be redundant?

Comment: "pretty much everything I write is a set I think" That's the idea ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer your last question

> Lastly if in modern axiomatic set theory essentially everything is a set wouldn't things like this:
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_function
>
> Be redundant?

Yes, it's redundant. In set theory, every function is a set function.

Comment: Wait so is the wikipedia page not a legit concept then? Also now that I think about it, why do people even quantify things by saying they are sets in the first place if like everything is.

Comment: @user3865391 Most mathematicians use the notions of sets informally and don't think in terms of set theory. To them a number is a number -- not a set. And then it makes sense to distinguish between 'normal' functions taking numbers as input and 'set' functions -- usually taking sets of numbers as input.

Comment: And boy, let me tell you, was I confused at first as an undergraduate dealing with both axiomatic set theory and basically everyone else working without an axiomatic foundation. (I still don't know/understand how they do it, to be honest.)

Comment: What should i do? I was studying a thing in combinatorics and a guy shows it can work also in counting it in when things are infinite but it requires set theory stuff involving cardinals.

Comment: @user3865391 What should you do about what?

Comment: soz  was studying a thing in combinatorics and a guy shows it can work also in counting it in when things are infinite but it requires set theory stuff involving cardinals. Like there was a theorem about counting things and he starts showing how it can be generalized to not finite analog, I want to try and do this thing myself. Like if I see a combinatorics problem about finite sets I want to generalize it but i cant if i dont do rigourous stiuff right>

Comment: @user3865391 To be honest, I have no idea how non-set-theorists deal with infinite cardinals. So I'm afraid I'm not the right person to ask this question. My suggestion would be to learn axiomatic set theory but that's a ridicilous response to your problem. It's like building a death star as a response to an argument with your neighbor. It's fun, though (learning axiomatic set theory that is -- I have yet to construct my death star).

Comment: @user3865391 Most mathematicians get by with a rudimentary understanding of set theory. One relevant discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/3uzuno/what_is_a_set_you_have_used_whose_cardinality_is/ this shows that most people only deal with finite sets, sets with the same cardinality as the natural numbers, sets with the same cardinality as the real numbers, and sets with the same cardinality as the power set of the real numbers.

Comment: I want to be able to do combinatorics stuff with infinite sets, I've seen theorems that have generalizations. Reduces for finite sets but holds for infinite counting to, this stuff looks very interesting but my set theory is not rigorous. Can I just learn about the cardinality in more advanced set theory or will that not work. If I'm going to like prove a theorem lets say about all graphs the structures with edges and vertex you know, I want to have my formula be good for all cardinality not just things as big as the reals. Why restrict oneself.

Comment: @user3865391 If you are only interested in countable objects, you don't need set theory. All you need to know is that for each infinite, countable set $X$ there is a bijection $\pi \colon \mathbb N \to X$.

Comment: @user3865391 It's easier to just learn about cardinality semi-formally; there are "transition to advanced mathematics" courses and books along these lines.

Comment: @StefanMesken I want to be able to prove things for as wide range as possible. Like if there is a theorem about graphs $G=\{\{x,y\}:x,y\in V\}$, I would want to try and show it holds for all graphs of any cardinality. I dont want to deliberately make it less generalized by saying no only graphs this big it can work for. I can't prove new theorem now, but one day if i study hard enough. I don't want to cripple myself only working with stuff cardinality at most reals or whatever you knowq

Comment: @user3865391 Well, isn't that what we all want? Unfortunately, that's pretty much impossible. You will always be limited by your lack of knowledge -- no matter what you do. In modern day mathematics you can only hope to carve out a small area of expertise for yourself and deciding which subjects to study will (in part) decide where those areas lie. If you decide to study axiomatic set theory, you will be able to tackle questions in combinatorics/graph theory/... that most mathematicians don't have access to. But you will also miss a lot of different tools that they are equipped with.

Comment: @StefanMesken So I can't be a good working mathematician who uses rigorous axiom set theory to prove things for more general? What if I want to work groups who have cardinality like $7$ consecutive powersets of real number cardinality $\aleph_{7}$ then how can I do that.

Comment: @user3865391 You absolutely can. It takes a couple of weeks (maybe months) to get a solid handle on the basics of axiomatic set theory. If you want to take that time, you can definitely learn how to write proofs in this axiomatic setting and then continue in any direction you want. Most mathematicians just choose not to bother with that.

Comment: @StefanMesken Why do they not bother with it? If I do this will it hurt me if I study other math later?

Comment: @user3865391 You changed the central question of your previous comment after I had responded to an earlier version. So let me respond to the new version as well:  If you are only interested in cardinals, I don't think you need set theory (but, as I've said before, I don't really know how one would go about that without set theory -- I'm certain there is a way, but I don't know it myself).

Comment: @StefanMesken I accepted your answer Im sorry.

Comment: @user3865391 An understanding of the basics of axiomatic set theory will never hurt you -- just like an understanding of the basics of functional analysis will never hurt me.

Comment: @user3865391 I wouldn't even know what you could possibly be sorry about :-)

Comment: @StefanMesken For asking so many questions. I can google "axiom set theory free pdf" but often something I don't understand comes up and all I can do is keep trying to learn from other source re-read it until maybe I understand then ask here. I was studying a combinatorics book and a chapter on counting stuff with sets, I started thinking about doing same arguments for infinite ones. So I read other stuff, and now this is what I want to learn more about, I have found for problems it requires doing stuff that I have seen done with cardinal numbers but dont understand it totally. Anyway thanks u

Comment: @user3865391 Yeah, learning mathematics outside of a provided course often feels like one is constantly back-tracking... If you are serious about learning axiomatic set theory, I would suggest Enderton's "Elements of Set Theory" to you. (Or, ideally, a course at your university on set theory.) You can also search this site for a study guide on axiomatic set theory -- there are a couple of relevant questions and excellent answers.

Comment: @StefanMesken Thank you. Is this the book you are referring to? http://azadimath.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Elements_of_set_theory_vol_1.pdf

Comment: @user3865391 Yes, that's the one.

Comment: Stefan Mesken Thanks I am thankful for book advice, I'm looking at table of context though and only the chapters $6,7,8,9$ and maybe review $2$. Is this good you think? I don't want to re-construct again real number setc.

Comment: @user3865391 Do you know how to construct real numbers from nothing but sets? If you don't, I'd suggest going through the details. It's not as much about the result but the construction will teach you how to think in a axiomatic set theory.

Comment: @user3865391: I just want to respond to one of your comments about graphs. In ZFC there **cannot exist** a set of all graphs, because from such a set (via the rest of the ZFC axioms) we can obtain a set of all sets, which we already know leads to a contradiction. If you (and/or Stefan) want to discuss this further, you're welcome to do so in [the Logic chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic).

Comment: @StefanMesken: The easiest way to explain normal mathematical practice is via some kind of type theory, or at least set theory with urelements. Non-set-theorists think (rightfully so) of natural numbers as urelements that satisfy [PA−](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations) plus induction for any 1-natural-parameter sentence. After all, philosophically we cannot reduce this any further [non-circularly](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/42164/what-are-the-arguments-for-and-against-one-true-arithmetic).

Comment: But it's true that in ZFC there is this nice construction of ordinals that make it convenient to have the (current) axiom of infinity rather than some arbitrary model of PA, though as per my previous comment we can only justify natural numbers as being some arbitrary abstraction of some empirical real-world interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

For any non-empty set $X$, *some* element of $X$ is disjoint from it; this is the axiom of regularity. But not all $x \in X$ are required to have this property. Consider for instance $X=\{ \emptyset,\{ \emptyset \} \}$: $\{ \emptyset \}$ is an element of $X$ which is not disjoint from $X$.

The fact that not *all* $x$ in $X$ are required to have this property is actually important in how we might use ZF to do other math. For instance, $\{ \emptyset,\{ \emptyset \} \}$ is the "bare metal" representation of the ordinal number "2", and in general the ordinal number $n+1$ is given by $n \cup \{ n \}$.

Comment: Ok that was a really simple counter example, now I feel retarded. I kinda wana delete the question cause it makes me look stupid but Im grateful for your time can you answer me this though. How about the conditions for $\emptyset=X\cap \left(\bigcup_{x\in X}x\right)$ or like a way to find the cafrdinality of $X\cup \left(\bigcup_{x\in X}x\right)$ if not disjoint ever. If I can get this it was my main hope in asking the question.

Comment: @user3865391 Often they will be disjoint, but I don't know of any nice recipe for showing that. As you can see here, the usual representation of the finite ordinals shows a case where "most" elements of $X$ intersect with $X$.

Comment: I am afraid I do not know exactly what an ordinal is, basically my very bad understanding from trying to read wikipedia is it keeps track of the cardinality and the ordering so its like a cardinal with an order structure or something.

Comment: @user3865391 The concept of ordinals is irrelevant to this discussion. It's just the go-to example where such a counterexample occurs. (To set theorists and ordinal roughly is what a natural number is to any other mathematician.)

Comment: @user3865391 The first finite ordinal is $\emptyset$, which we think of as $0$. The others are given by the recursion $n+1=n \cup \{ n \}$. This is really all you need to know to understand my answer, you don't need to know why you would do this seemingly weird thing.